# Creating a censoring function from a list of bad words

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a function that censors words in a string. It's kinda working, with a few quirks.

This is my code:

```
def censor(sentence):
    badwords = 'apple orange banana'.split()
    sentence = sentence.split()

    for i in badwords:
        for words in sentence:
            if i in words:
                pos = sentence.index(words)
                sentence.remove(words)
                sentence.insert(pos, '*' * len(i))

    print " ".join(sentence)

sentence = "you are an appletini and apple. new sentence: an orange is a banana. orange test."

censor(sentence)
```

And the output:

```
you are an ***** and ***** new sentence: an ****** is a ****** ****** test.
```

Some punctuation is gone and the word `"appletini"` is replaced wrongly.

How can this be fixed?

Also, is there any simpler way of doing this kind of thing?

Comment: Beware of the [Scunthorpe Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Comment: Note to potential editors: [Relevant Meta Post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251102/how-should-bad-language-be-handled).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific problems are that:

1. You don't consider punctuation at all; and
2. You use the length of the "bad word", not the word, when inserting `'*'`s.

I would switch the loop order around, so you only process the sentence once, and use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) rather than `remove` and `insert`:

```
def censor(sentence):
    badwords = ("test", "word") # consider making this an argument too
    sentence = sentence.split()

    for index, word in enumerate(sentence):
        if any(badword in word for badword in badwords):
            sentence[index] = "".join(['*' if c.isalpha() else c for c in word])

    return " ".join(sentence) # return rather than print
```

Testing [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) will replace only upper- and lower-case letters with asterisks. Demo:

```
>>> censor("Censor these testing words, will you? Here's a test-case!")
"Censor these ******* *****, will you? Here's a ****-****!"
            # ^ note length                         ^ note punctuation
```

Comment: bookending the bad words with regex word boundaries would solve the punctuation problem.

Comment: @kojiro as you've already pointed out so succinctly in the question comments, writing a censorship program like this is always going to have issues, so there seemed no point to further complicating things with regular expressions!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm new to python so I haven't used 'any' and enumerate much yet, but I will play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in bad_word_list:
    sentence = sentence.replace(i, '*' * len(i))
```